# array does not generate using array.from in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have started a raffle app (of sorts) that i'm having some trouble with. i am converting it to ES6 and somewhere along the line i may have messed something up.

the end goal at the moment is just to display a set of pictures with their captions on the screen. the captions come from the names array and display fine, but the images do not show at all and i do not get errors in the console.

i named my images in a way that it can be iterated through (team0, team1, team2, etc). the names come from a textarea and the numbers array is created based on the length of the names array and is supposed to fill with numbers but does not fill at all, causing the img tags i'm making to have no source and not display the images. so if my names array had 2 names in it, the numbers array should be [0,1]. here's the lines that are the focus of this question. followed by the whole code.

```
var names = [];
var numbers = Array.from({length:names.length}).map((_,i)=>i);

    if (e.target.id === "baseball") {
           newImg.src = "images/baseball/team" + numbers[i] + ".jpg";
         } else if (e.target.id === "football") {
           newImg.src = "images/football/team" + numbers[i] + ".gif";
         }
         tDisplay.appendChild(newDiv);
```

is this the most efficient way of doing this? here is my whole code.

```
var random = document.getElementById("random");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var tDisplay = document.getElementById("parent");
var bGroup = document.getElementById("buttonGroup");
var dBtn = document.getElementById("display");
var names = [];
var numbers = Array.from({length:names.length}).map((_,i)=>i); //creates a numbers array that is the same length as the names array, for indexing.



var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

// save names without submitting
function saveNames() {
  names = textarea.value.split('\n');
}
// save names to array, no submit button
textarea.addEventListener('blur', saveNames, false);


// shuffle arrays
function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
  }
}


function newEls(e) {
  tDisplay.innerHTML = "";
  names.forEach(function(name, i) {

        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var newImg = document.createElement("img");
        var userName = document.createElement("p");

        newDiv.className = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2"
        newDiv.appendChild(newImg);
        newDiv.appendChild(userName);
        userName.textContent = name;

        if (e.target.id === "baseball") {
               newImg.src = "images/baseball/team" + numbers[i] + ".jpg";
             } else if (e.target.id === "football") {
               newImg.src = "images/football/team" + numbers[i] + ".gif";
             }
             tDisplay.appendChild(newDiv);

  });
}

// display images before random
dBtn.addEventListener("click", function images(e) {
    newEls(e);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `numbers` array always be empty since `names` is empty? You should do the `Array.from` inside `saveNames()`, right?

Comment: that makes sense... i've tried this and it finally filled. thank you!

Comment: Also, do you really need the `numbers` array? If you're only using it to set the img src, you can just simply use `i`.

Comment: @dork that is what I was thinking although maybe they use it somewhere else in their program, python style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code. First of all, `e.targetId` is never baseball or football, it is always "display". This is because the function executes when the element with the id "display" is clicked. I assume you want to see if that checkbox is checked. In that case, change your if statement to this:

```
if (document.getElementById('baseball').checked) {
           newImg.src = "images/baseball/team" + numbers[i] + ".jpg";
         } else if (document.getElementById('football').checked) {
           newImg.src = "images/football/team" + numbers[i] + ".gif";
         }
```

The other thing is what [@dork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/769326/dork) mentioned, which is where you define your `numbers` array. Put it in the `saveNames()` function like so:

```
function saveNames() {
  names = textarea.value.split('\n');
  numbers = Array.from({length:names.length}).map((_,i)=>i); //creates a numbers array that is the same length as the names array, for indexing.
}
```

And then up the top where you were defining it originally just put

```
var numbers;
```

---

Another thing - I can't say based on the rest of your code, but to me the `numbers` array seems redundant (i.e. `numbers[i]` will always be the same as `i` itself). If you want to get rid of that then don't bother defining the `numbers` array and just replace `numbers[i]` with `i`:

```
if (document.getElementById('baseball').checked) {
           newImg.src = "images/baseball/team" + i + ".jpg";
         } else if (document.getElementById('football').checked) {
           newImg.src = "images/football/team" + i + ".gif";
         }
```

**NOTE:** In case you were wondering, this is based on the HTML you put in the question originally, but it seems you deleted it.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i actually imposed all these changes you mentioned after i realized it would make more sense to see if the radio buttons were checked. some of that was old code when i left the radio buttons as regular buttons before i started converting things. i removed the HTML code.

Comment: @user2247061 just out of interest do you need the `numbers` array for anything else or can you just use `i`?

Comment: At the moment I don't use it anywhere else, though the app isn't really complete so I'm not sure yet and will further expand on it later on. I did not try using just i yet, but you were right, it is redundant.